# OpenGL rendering & display in different processes

Tags: windows, opengl, off-screen

What are the solutions on Windows to split the OpenGL rendering from the display?

By that I mean that a process in the background takes care of the whole scene drawing, and a separate process should simply render a texture with the result.

Most likely browsers have some solution today to handle rendering in various sub-processes.

On Linux, we can use EGL_MESA_IMAGE_DMA_BUF_EXPORT, as demonstrated in https://blaztinn.gitlab.io/post/dmabuf-texture-sharing/

Comment: This is what OpenGL does by default, what is shown in the window is simply a frame buffer. OpenGL calls will render to the back buffer, when a new frame is ready the buffers as swapped. If you're talking about putting OpenGL code in a different thread that's a different matter

Comment: @PeteBlackerThe3rd more than a different thread, I would like part of the rendering to be done in a different process. See also the Linux DMABUF article, I would like to achieve something similar on Windows. Thanks

Comment: I see. There is an answer to this question [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387049/share-opengl-frame-buffer-render-buffer-between-two-applications ] which seems to be the same as yours. Does this help?

Comment: @PeteBlackerThe3rd thanks for the link. Indeed, it's the same question. I'll close this one.